# how to covert time to decimal jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to convert a time to a decimal number.
I want it in this input value

this is my code;

```
<input type="text" id="time3" class="form-control time">
```

I have 2 other inputs with time. I want to compare that time and convert the endtime to decimal.

```
<input type="text" id="time1" class="form-control time" value="@s">
<input type="text" id="time2" class="form-control time">
```

who can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by decimal number? Are you trying to convert a date string to a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: Example input/output values?

Comment: what im trying to do is compare the two times, and the last time convert to a decimal. for example: 14:15 - 14:00 = 15 minutes => 0,25

Answer (score 0):

Save your values as Date object

```
var date1 = new Date("7/11/2010 10:45");
var date2 = new Date("7/11/2010 11:00");
```

Calculate time difference:

```
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
```

And finally get value in hours:

```
var diffByHour = timeDiff / (1000 * 3600); 
alert(diffByHour);
```